# Mysql NOT ON statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

i have the following query that pulls posts that belong to a blog

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM  `Posts` p
INNER JOIN Blogs b ON b.id = p.blog_id
```

Is there a MySQL function that does the opposite of "ON"? If i wanted to query posts that didn't belong to a blog in the "Blogs" database table? For instance if the blog was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the JOIN.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM  `Posts` p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Blogs b ON b.id = p.blog_id

WHERE b.Id IS NULL
```

Should do the trick for you.

Jeff Atwood has a [great overview](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) of joins

In this instance, what the LEFT OUTER JOIN does is match all rows in Blogs with all rows in Posts with the same blog_id-Id combo AND all rows in Posts that have no matching Id in Blogs. In this instance, those rows are NULL for the entries in Blogs (as there aren't any!), which is why we filter on `b.Id IS NULL`

There are some other ways you can achieve this too; for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE blog_id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Blogs)
```

Effectively, this queries all rows in posts that have a blog_id that isn't in the blog table.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use either `LEFT JOIN - NULL` combo, like this:

```
         SELECT p.*
           FROM Posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Blogs b
             ON b.id = p.blog_id
          WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

... or `NOT IN` dependent query (with so-called 'anti-join'):

```
       SELECT * 
         FROM Posts 
        WHERE blog_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Blogs)
```

I admit I almost exclusively use the first form, but actually they have the similar performance: I'd recommend at least glancing through [**this article**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) with detailed explanation of similarities and differences between these queries; it's quite an enlightening reading. )